# Authorize to Facebook - error

Tags: c#, facebook, asynchronous

This error shows up when i want to authorize to Facebook.

> An error has occurred. 
>   Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
>   
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
>    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   BotApplication.Facebook.FacebookHelpers.<FacebookRequest>d__9`1.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\BotApplication\Application\Facebook\FacebookHelpers.cs:line
>   129 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at
>   BotApplication.Facebook.FacebookHelpers.<ExchangeCodeForAccessToken>d__2.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\BotApplication\BotApplication\Facebook\FacebookHelpers.cs:line
>   62 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at
>   BotApplication.Controllers.OAuthCallbackController.d__0.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\BotApplication\BotApplication\Controllers\OAuthCallbackController.cs:line
>   46 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()

Application throws an error on this line :

```
 json = await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Any idea to solve this ?

Comment: You have to include a lot more information about the call you are making.  What is `uri`? How is it built?

Answer (score 1):

The exception shows why your code doesn't work, have a look.
"An error has occurred. Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)". 
If you read about what does 400 response means, you'll get idea of about it.
It could happen due to several reasons, it could be the authentication, it could be the wrong formatted url etc... Kindly have a look within your uri variable what you are passing there.